# How to get current logged-in user details in multisite?

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

When I logged into the specific multi-site, I am trying to get current login user details, I already used below one but this function returning null. How, can I get currents logged in user information.
I am actually trying to get user email

```
$logged_in_user = wp_get_current_user();

if($logged_in_user->ID != 0){
    $email = $logged_in_user->user_email;
}
```

Comment: It should work. It's possible you're using it too early in the page load, before the current user has been determined. When are you running the function?

Comment: `get_currentuserinfo()` , so you can use. It's important, though, to only call it on or after the init hook. Calling it before will only return 0

Comment: wp_get_current_user() return this object WP_User object {
  back_compat_keys => array(6) (
    [user_firstname] => (string) first_name
    [user_lastname] => (string) last_name
    [user_description] => (string) description
    [user_level] => (string) wp_user_level
    [wp_usersettings] => (string) wp_user-settings
    [wp_usersettingstime] => (string) wp_user-settings-time
  )
  data => stdClass object
  ID => (int) 0
  caps => array(0)
  cap_key => null
  roles => array(0)
  allcaps => array(0)
  filter => null
}

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user), you have call this inside a hook.

> For wordpress versions < 3.4: use the init or any subsequent action to call this function. Calling it outside of an action can lead to troubles. See #14024 for details.

Example:

```
add_action('init', 'get_user_email');
function get_user_email() {
  $logged_in_user = wp_get_current_user();

  if($logged_in_user->ID != 0){
    $email = $logged_in_user->user_email;
  }
}
```

Comment: I used that hook then also showing                                              
  WP_User object { back_compat_keys => array(6) ( [user_firstname] => (string) first_name [user_lastname] => (string) last_name [user_description] => (string) description [user_level] => (string) wp_user_level [wp_usersettings] => (string) wp_user-settings [wp_usersettingstime] => (string) wp_user-settings-time ) data => stdClass object ID => (int) 0 caps => array(0) cap_key => null roles => array(0) allcaps => array(0) filter => null }

Comment: Try the `global $current_user;`